# SpriteKit how to add a fixedJoint?

Tags: sprite-kit, skphysicsjoint

I'm trying to bind two nodes together with a fixed SKPhysicsJoint
I came up with this Code:

```
var anchor = CGPointMake(hero.position.x + 10,hero.position.y)
var fixedJoint = [SKPhysicsJointFixed .jointWithBodyA(hero.physicsBody!, bodyB: shield.physicsBody!, anchor: anchor)]
```

the problem came with:

```
self.physicsWorld.addJoint(fixedJoint)
```

It gave me this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[SKPhysicsJointFixed]' to expected argument type 'SKPhysicsJoint'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the fixedJoint into an array, try this instead, omitting [ and ].

```
let anchor = CGPointMake(hero.position.x + 10,hero.position.y)
let fixedJoint = SKPhysicsJointFixed.jointWithBodyA(hero.physicsBody!, bodyB: shield.physicsBody!, anchor: anchor)
```

Note: If you are not mutating your properties make them let instead of var.